# Extract substrings where match is found

Tags: string, powershell, search, substring, powershell-3.0

I have a text file with a number of lines. I would like to search each line individually for a particular pattern and, if that pattern is found output a substring at a particular position relative to where the pattern was found.

i.e. if a line contains the pattern at position 20, I would like to output the substring that begins at position 25 on the same line and lasts for five characters.

The following code will output every line that contains the pattern:

```
select-string -path C:\Scripts\trimatrima\DEBUG.txt -pattern $PATTERN
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: _>where do i go from here?_ https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$Matches` automatic variable:

Last match is stored in `$Matches[0]`, but you can also use named capture groups, like this:

```
"test","fest","blah" |ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match "^[bf](?<groupName>es|la).$"){
        $Matches["groupName"]
    }
}
```

returns `es` (from "fest") and `la` (from "blah")

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options.

Keeping `Select-String`, you'll want to use the `.line` property to get your substrings:

```
select-string -path C:\Scripts\trimatrima\DEBUG.txt -pattern $PATTERN |
 foreach { $_.line.Substring(19,5) }
```

For large files, `Get-Content` with `-ReadCount` and `-match` may be faster:

```
Get-Content C:\Scripts\trimatrima\DEBUG.txt-ReadCount 1000 |
 foreach {
  $_ -match $pattern |
  foreach { $_.substring(19,5) }
  }
```

Comment: I think what would be helpful would be to mention a positive look behind, since with your second method he could just do something like `GC $file -readcount 1000|ForEach{$_ -replace "(?<=$Pattern).{5}(.{5})",'$1'}` (maybe even without the ForEach? I'm not sure, you'd know better than I)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do the look behind.  Just add the beginning of line anchor, and wildcard the first 20  characters.

Comment: From his original post I was under the impression that the string could be located anywhere in the line, and he wants a substring 5 characters after the pattern, wherever the pattern happens to be found. I may have misunderstood.

Comment: That's the way I read it, too.  Looks like the question was edited after I posted this answer.